# LED selection for my application

Tags: led, light, lighting

I need to select LED/LEDs for a light source in my project. The requirement is that the light source should approximately be able to project light beam of 1.5m diameter on a surface, from a distance of 1.5m. The incident light should have lux equal to 1500. 
How do I go about selecting the LEDs for this application? What factors should be considered?[image: Diagram attached to illustrate the scenario]

Comment: Figure out how many watts of light output you need, and find an LED that's rated for that. If you need the beam to have that specific a shape, you're probably going to need to add lenses yourself.

Comment: Buy a suitable flashlight.

Comment: LEDs typically don't just cast a beam out of the box, there's surrounding peripherals to gather all the light (usually in a pretty wide cone, maybe 170degrees) and focus it. In particular, I'd look at Total Internal Reflection lenses (TIR) in conjunction with the other advice given here.

Comment: lux is a unit, you want an **illuminance** of 15000 lux. You should consider whether the illuminance should be homogeneous in the drawn circle of 1.5 meter (quite hard to achieve i think) Or is illuminance allowed to be not homogeneous and do you want just 15000 lux at the centre or at least 15000 lux at the circumference of said drawn circle? If it should be homogeneous, dont forget to take the spatial distribution of the LED into account.

Comment: 15000 lux should be the OP's 1500 lux of course...

Comment: If you want a more or less even wash across the width of the spot, most of the flashlights I have with that property use a clear plastic optic that is flat on the LED side and a section of a sphere(not quite a full hemisphere) on the outside.  A second low profile conical lens is often used around the LED to reduce wastage of light projected sideways.  Moving the lens to a different depth allows you to focus the beam(change the width) without disturbing the wash overly, but the farther the lens moves out, the less efficient the optics become unless you increase the size of the cone optic.

Comment: If you want to see an example in real life, camping stores will often let you test flashlights without purchasing them, or a "Police Security"(brand) "Bearcat"(model) is a cheap example you may be able to find at your local Wal-Mart.  This brand uses "Try me" type packaging.  The bulk of readily available optics are "spot/thrower" or "spot/flood" and do not have this uniformity of wash, so hopefully if you haven't taken an optics course, that will give you an idea of what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a lumens to lux calculator, given beam angle and distance.

https://www.bannerengineering.com/us/en/company/expert-insights/lux-lumens-calculator.html

Looks like ~2300 lumen would yield ~1500 lux at 45 degrees and 1.5 meter.

Might look at "tactical flashlights" like these and see what kind of LED & lenses they use to achieve 1300 lumen, go from there, use 2 of them kind of thing.

Comment: I think the beam angle should be 2*arctan(1/2) = 53°.